# Can't install any packages on RHEL because of dependencies

Tags: rhel, package-management, repository

I am trying to install packages, but I keep getting dependency errors.

I already installed the EPEL, IUS, REMI repos.

Example:

```
yum install gcc
```

and I get

```
Error: Package: devtoolset-2-gcc-4.8.2-15.1.el6.x86_64 (slc6-devtoolset) 
requires: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12   (and other dependencies)
```

and when I try to install glibc (or the other dependencies)

```
yum install glibc-devel*
```

I get

```
no package glibc-devel* available.  Nothing to do.


yum list installed |grep glibc*
```

does not show any glibc-devel installed.

RHEL Version = 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, replace, security, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id                        repo name                          status
InstallMedia                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.4       disabled
epel                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu enabled: 11,141
epel-debuginfo                 Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-source                    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-testing                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
epel-testing-source            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linu disabled
ius                            IUS Community Packages for Enterpr enabled:    232
ius-archive                    IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-archive-debuginfo          IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-archive-source             IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-debuginfo                  IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-dev                        IUS Community Packages for Enterpr enabled:     25
ius-dev-debuginfo              IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-dev-source                 IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-source                     IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-testing                    IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-testing-debuginfo          IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
ius-testing-source             IUS Community Packages for Enterpr disabled
pgdg93                         PostgreSQL 9.3 6Server - x86_64    enabled:    256
pgdg93-source                  PostgreSQL 9.3 6Server - x86_64 -  disabled
remi                           Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Li disabled
remi-debuginfo                 Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Li disabled
remi-php55                     Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour En disabled
remi-php55-debuginfo           Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.5 pour En disabled
remi-php56                     Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour En disabled
remi-php56-debuginfo           Les RPM de remi de PHP 5.6 pour En disabled
remi-test                      Les RPM de remi en test pour Enter disabled
remi-test-debuginfo            Les RPM de remi en test pour Enter disabled
rhel-source                    Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server - disabled
rhel-source-beta               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6Server B disabled
rpmforge                       RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - dag  enabled:  4,718
rpmforge-extras                RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - extr disabled
rpmforge-testing               RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - test disabled
slc6-devtoolset                Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - D enabled:    458
slc6-devtoolset-debug          Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - D disabled
slc6-devtoolset-source         Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - D disabled
slc6-devtoolset-testing        Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - D disabled
slc6-devtoolset-testing-debug  Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - D disabled
slc6-devtoolset-testing-source Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - D disabled
slc6-os                        Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) bas disabled
webtatic                       Webtatic Repository 6Server - x86_ enabled:    383
webtatic-debuginfo             Webtatic Repository 6Server - x86_ disabled
webtatic-source                Webtatic Repository 6Server - x86_ disabled
repolist: 17,213
```

Comment: Do an update "# yum update"

Comment: Please add the output of `yum repolist all` to your question.

Comment: You should be installing the `gcc` package from `slc6-os.repo` or `slc6-updates.repo`, then the dependancies will be provided from there too rather than using the `devtoolset` version.

Comment: @geedoubleya I looked for instructions for downloading and installing the slc6-os repo but found none.  On cern's own site (http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific6/docs/softwaremgmt.shtml) I found the text for the .repo file and created it in my /etc/yum.repos.d, but when I did a yum update - I got 1200+ updates and 422M!  I cancelled that, and tried "yum install gcc" and it downloaded the 12 files, but failed during the GPGKey check.  I compared the gpgkey check line to the one in an existing "slc6-devtoolset" on my system, and it matched.  not sure why it's failing or what to try next

Comment: You need to indent *each* line by at least 4 spaces for it to format as code/output in the final output (and preview).

Comment: Does `rpm --import http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern` help?

Comment: @garethTheRed I'm a little puzzled by your comment - I thought it's clear I'm fairly unfamiliar with SE, and I am guessing you are far more familiar.  Anyway, so you can help a future person with that problem better, here's a better way I just figured out: If you want to post many lines without indenting each and every line with 4 spaces (especially for the 40+ lines of output you asked for) you 1) paste the output in the editor 2) highlight it 3) select "{}" in the editor.  Now I have done that - and it was much quicker than indenting each line individually.

Comment: @geedoubleya - Yes! Thanks for helping to get that working for me.   Now I'm wondering if I should go ahead with all 1200+ / 400M updates its prompting for after enabling that repo?

Comment: No worries - useful tip, to indent all code in the SE editor, select it and type `Ctrl-k` @gareth too.

Comment: @geedoubleya - how do I give you credit for answering my question?

Comment: Embarrassingly, I hadn't noticed the `{}` in the editor and have been laboriously adding 4 spaces to each line in all my posts :-o. Thanks for pointing it out - that will definitely help save some time in the future. @geedoubleya - so it does! Every day's a school day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be installing the `gcc` package from

`slc6-os.repo` or `slc6-updates.repo`

Then the dependancies will be provided from there too rather than using the `devtoolset` version.

*Yum Repositories Entries*

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-os.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-updates.repo
/etc/yum.repos.d/slc6-extras.repo
```

[Installation instructions](http://linux.web.cern.ch/linux/scientific6/docs/softwaremgmt.shtml)

*Location:*

[slc6-os.repo](http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/)
[slc6-updates.repo](http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/updates/)
[slc6-extras.repo](http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/extras/)

*Import the GPG key:*

```
rpm --import http://linuxsoft.cern.ch/cern/slc6X/x86_64/RPM-GPG-KEY-cern
```

Answer (score 0):

glibc-devel should be part of the base repo, you may have a some conflicts with your repos.

try disabling all the extra repos you added and try again.

You should also check yum [Priorities](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) plug-in which can prevent a 3rd party repository from replacing base packages, or prevent base/updates from replacing a 3rd party package.